# mysql one to many relation is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Having some trouble adding a relation between tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
`emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`emp_fname` char(50) NOT NULL,
`emp_sname` char(50) NOT NULL,
`emp_patr` char(50) NOT NULL,
`emp_birth` datetime NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`isInCharge` boolean default NULL,
`depart_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department` (
`depart_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`depart_name` char(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`depart_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (depart_id) REFERENCES employees (depart_id) on delete 
cascade on update cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

What is going wrong? I need to make possible for many employees to be in one department.

Also, how can I generate a random birth date from 1950 to 1990?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your foreign key is in the wrong place.  It belongs in the `employees` table not the `department` table.  And it should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (depart_id) REFERENCES department(depart_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
```

This should be easy to remember.  You define the *primary* key in the table where the column is unique.  You define the *foreign* key in all tables that refer to that primary key.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the other way around right? dept_Id in Employee shall be foriegn key referencing the primary key Dept_ID of Department.